# change props value of a child component causing too many renders

Tags: react-native

child component takes a prop. Now from button click of the parent, i want to continue updating the prop so that the child component can update itself with new calculated result

```
       const childComponent = ({value}) =>{
        const [total, updateTotal] = useState('enter 0 or higher value and hit calculate button');
        const calculateTotal = () =>{
          updateTotal(value * 0.25);
        }

        useEffect(()=>{
          if (value>0){
             calculateTotal();
            }
          
        }, [value]);

       return (<Text>{total}</Text>)
       }
```

ParentComponent:

```
        const [value, updateValue]= useState(0);
        const generateValue = ()=>{
          //logic that generates a number
          const numberGenerated = generateValue();
          updateValue(numberGenerated); 
          }
        return (<View><ChildComponent value={value}/> <Button onPress={generateValue}>Calculate</Button></View>)
```

But when I click the button, it says :

```
Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you missed the arrow function:

```
 <Button onPress={()=>generateValue()}>Calculate</Button>
```